# Why is this code not performant? Updating inner text vs replacing entire tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Can someone explain why this code isn't working. If you click the cats quickly, it freezes the browser.

```
    render: function(catName){
                var cat = controller.getCat(catName);
                var displayArea = $('#displayArea');
                var catImage = $('#catImage');
                var num = $('#numClicks');
                // the two lines below are not performant
                catImage.attr('src', cat.url);
                num.text(cat.numClicks);
                // the three lines below can replace the two lines above and they work. Why?
                //displayArea.empty();
                //displayArea.append('<img src=\"' + cat.url + '\"' + '</img>');
                //displayArea.append('<p>' + cat.numClicks + '</p>');
                $("#displayArea img").click(function(){
                    cat.numClicks++;
                    controller.updateClicks(cat.name, cat.numClicks);
                    view.render(cat.name);
                });

    }
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ryangittens/fo2g24dp/1/

Comment: Where is `#catImage` relative to `#displayArea`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're constantly **re**-hooking the `click` event. Changing the `src` of an `img` doesn't unhook the handlers. (Note that I'm assuming, partially on the basis of the commented-out code, that `#catImage` is *inside* `#displayArea`.)

Just hook `click` on `$("#displayArea img")` **once**.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are adding a click event every time `render` is called.

try

```
$("#displayArea img").off('click',).on('click', function(){
  cat.numClicks++;
  controller.updateClicks(cat.name, cat.numClicks);
  view.render(cat.name);
});
```

This will remove previously bound events

Comment: or you can move the click event outside of the render function

Comment: I ended up moving it outside the render function but this is useful and might have been quicker to implement.